# Pandas Merging Values Vertically by Group

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following dataframe

```
     name     note
0    jon      likes beer
1    jon      on tuesdays
2    steve    tonight
3    steve    we dine in heck
```

What I want is the following

```
     name     note
0    jon      likes beer on tuesdays
1    jon      likes beer on tuesdays
2    steve    tonight we dine in heck
3    steve    tonight we dine in heck
```

Is there a way to do this? I know you can merge vertically, but can you do it by groups?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `join`:

```
df['note'] = df.groupby('name')['note'].transform(' '.join)
```

Comment: Nice one and fast. +1

Comment: This did it, but I can't mark this as the answer so soon. I gotta wait 10 minutes.